# while, ifなどを連結する文法の可否について

Tags: java, c#, c++, c

C系の文法を持つ言語については以下のような記述が可能であると思います。

```
while (foo) if (hoge) {
    ...
}
```

これは、こちらの書き方よりもブロックネストを抑えることができるのが利点ですが、

```
while (foo) {
    if (hoge) {
        ...
    }
}
```

可読性的には「もしかしたら問題があるかもしれない」と考えています。

ただ、個人的にはネストを抑える効果は大きいと考えています。

この書き方は、一般的には問題がありますか？

Comment: 別に好きずきかと思いますけど、ブロックの対応範囲はあくまで`if`のもので`if`ブロックが実行されなくても`while`は実行されるわけですから連結イメージは良くないかもですね。後から編集してコードを付け足すことになり`while`にも`{ }`が必要になったような場合（長いソースの場合には特に）インデントがわかりにくいし、インデントを付け直す必要もあるかもしれません。

Comment: 主観的な要素が強い質問だとは思いますが…個人的には「無し」です。このような広域なブロック`{}`の省略は、プログラムの論理構造を誤読するリスクがあるため、絶対に避けるべきだと考えます。

Comment: BLUEPPIXYさん, yohjpさん  > ブロックの対応範囲, 論理構造を誤解…確かに、これはwhileが主点であるように見えないかもしれません…。 以後、この書き方はやめておこうかと思います、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 11, accepted):

個人の自由ですが、ネストを抑えるという観点であれば、

```
while (foo) {
    if (!hoge)
        continue;
    ...
}
```

と論理を反転し早期に脱出させます。

Comment: 早期脱出によれば、ネストは一瞬ですみますね…。 解決策をくださり、ありがとうございます！